C++ 11 Специальные функции элементы перемещения по умолчанию
Изучаю мануал по С++ 11 здесь:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/11
В мануале есть статья - Специальные функции элементы перемещения по умолчанию здесь:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3053.html
Как я понял смысл этого исправления- что когда есть (например) класс, то в нем надо указывать конструктор (оператор присваивания) перемещения = default потому что такая реализация лучше, чем если вобще ничего не указывать.
Я не до конца понял смысл этого исправления С++11 объясните пожалуйста простыми словами.

Они пытались добавить move-члены по умолчанию, по аналогии с copy, но это ломает столько унаследованного кода, что компилятор (почти? не уверен) никогда не декларирует move члены. Если вы хотите, чтобы экземпляры вашего класса быстро "мувались", вам следует явно определить move-члены используя = default. Извините за просторечия, это моё понимание.

Спасибо, очень полезный ответ, но можете в развернутом виде объяснить что значит "быстро "мувались"" - что значит быстро? быстрее компилировалось, быстрее выполнялось? что быстро? вы имеете ввиду что если указать =default то код будет выполняться быстрее, чем если не указать (оставить класс без move = default)?

move-семантика позволяет ускорить выполнение программы, если вы можете разрушить исходный объект и из его частей создать новый (разрушающее копирование или присвоение). Например: вектор копируется очень медленно, а переносится очень быстро. То есть, если вы добавили в свой объект все эти move-конструкторы и операторы присваивания, у компилятора больше возможностей создать быстрый код.
